# IntelliJ : How to put a GIT branch as the new master?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How can I promote a branch called "Crashalytics3" to be the master branch? See the picture for the situation.

### [image]

The master (origin/master) contains only a few files, while the branch Crashalytics3 contains many files.

I tried:

- Checkout of the master (origin) branch
- Selected the Crashalytics3 branch with "MERGE". It should merge this branch into the master branch.

The message is: "Already up to date". The master branch still contains 2 files.

Comment: It looks like they are already merged in the graph too.  Did a different commit that was also merged in delete the files or something?

Comment: I did a "rebase" can that had the effect? 
Anyway, how can I get that branch in the main branch? Get a different branch starting at the CrashAlytics3 branch, push it, and then merg it into the main branch?

Comment: Depending on what you did in the rebase, yeah.  Maybe go to the reflog and undo the rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, I finally managed to promote the branch as the master.

Step 1: I created a new branch based on the right branch. I made a minor change - I don't know if this forced the new branch into being ;-)

Step 2: Then I did:

> git checkout new_branch
>
> git merge --strategy=ours master
>
> git checkout master
>
> git merge new_branch

A final push of the master made the changes final.